# react native "net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" error

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, facebook-login, create-react-native-app

i'm using:

```
"expo": "^33.0.0",

"expo-facebook": "^5.0.1",

"firebase": "^6.3.0",

"react": "16.8.3",

"react-dom": "^16.8.6",

"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",

"react-native-web": "^0.11.4"
```

i'm trying to use **facebook** login with **firebase** but when make a request it fails with with **"net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"**.

i have tried loggin in with firebase email but i can not do it with facebook.
i'm creating project with create-react-native-app, what's wrong with the "react-native" library? should it have a version in front of it?

```
async loginWithFacebook(){
    try{
        const {type,token}= await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync('2400454433563485',{permissions: ['public_profile'],});

    console.log('Type-> ', type);
    if (type === 'success') {
      const credentials = f.auth().FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
      f.auth().signInWithCredential(credentials)
      .catch(( error ) => {
        console.log('Errrrrorrrr !!! ',error);
      });
    }
    }catch(error){
      console.log(`Errror ${counter++} !!!`,error);
    }
  }
```

when i make the request it should bring up facebook login page page to enter facebook username password to login with facebook as the expo document says
https://docs.expo.io/versions/v33.0.0/sdk/facebook/

Comment: Note: Not compatible with web.

Comment: what do you mean? [hong develop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11212074/hong-develop)

Answer (score 0):

i created a new project and copied all the code again and installed dependencies again, this time it worked !!!